# Laravel checking if POST !isset then redirect throwing an error

Tags: laravel, routes

Currently have a POST route setup in Laravel

```
Route::post('/confirm', 'MainController@confirm');
```

**'/confirm'** makes use of some POST information sent over from the previous page.

What I am trying to accomplish is, if a user just types in **'index/confirm'** into the url and not all of the POST info is present redirect to **'index'**

I have the below code and cannot see why this would not work. I think it may be because inorder for the route to trigger at least some POST info needs to be present and if none is then error.

```
$input = $request->all();

if ( !isset($input) ) {
  return redirect('');
}
```

Error message:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

/Users/&name/Desktop/$filepath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

```
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

Comment: "[...] types in 'index/confirm' into the url" That's a `GET` request, not a `POST`; you're getting a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` since you don't have `Route::get("/index/confirm", ...);`

Comment: Do you have not found or 404 page?

Comment: You can create a `get` route with the same url and handle it separately

Comment: Thank you. Added a Get route

Comment: "What I am trying to accomplish is, if a user just types in 'index/confirm' into the url" the `get` route would only catch those cases,

Answer (score 0):

Commenters answered my question. Needed a seperate route for GET to handle unallowed user submitted url requests.

```
Route::get('/confirm', 'MainController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's fine for guarding one endpoint, but there's a more sweeping solution you can apply.  Look to your App\Exceptions\Handler class.  The `render()` method is given an awareness of the failed request, and the specific error that was thrown.  `public function render($request, Exception $e) ...`.  Add this:

```
if ($e instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
    return redirect('/index');
}
```

Just be careful with this.  If you typo your redirect URL, you'll end up in an infinite loop.  I'd also recommend an additional condition that respects the value of `config('app.env')` for debugging purposes.